# Создание таблицы пользователя

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Как создать таблицу только для чтения без возможности выделения, редактирования содержимого таблицы и его размера.

Я сделал чтобы в таблице нельзя было редактировать содержимое и его размер, и хотел создать иллюзию отсутствия возможности выделения, по средством создания двух таблиц и с помощью stylesheet замены цвета выделения на фоновый, но я не нашёл как удалить прерывистую линию и изменить размер колонку ряда.

сейчас это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хочу чтобы это выглядело так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(440, 450)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget {\n"
"    selection-background-color: #ffffff;\n"
"    selection-color: #000000;\n"
"    gridline-color: #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QHeaderView::section {\n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
"    border-style: none;\n"
"    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"    border-right: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QTableWidget QTableCornerButton::section {\n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
"    border: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QHeaderView::section:horizontal\n"
"{\n"
"    border-top: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QHeaderView::section:vertical\n"
"{\n"
"    border-left: 1px solid #000000;\n"
"}\n"
"QTableWidget {\n"
"    border: 0px solid ;\n"
"}\n"
"/*QScrollBar*/\n"
"QScrollBar:horizontal {\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"    background: #595959;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {\n"
"    border-radius: 8;\n"
"    background: #ffffff;\n"
"    min-width: 20px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal{\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"    background: #595959;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical {\n"
"    border-radius: 8;\n"
"    background: #ffffff;\n"
"    min-width: 20px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical{\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 440, 24))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 24, 440, 426))
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        mas_column = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(mas_column))
        for i in range(len(mas_column)):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily('Montserrat')
            font.setPointSize(6)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            item.setFont(font)
            item.setText(mas_column[i])
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(440//len(mas_column))
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)

        mas_row = ['1', '2', '3']
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(len(mas_column) - 1)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(len(mas_row))
        self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        for i in range(len(mas_row)):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily('Montserrat')
            font.setPointSize(6)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            item.setFont(font)
            item.setText(mas_row[i])
            self.tableWidget_2.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)
        self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(440//len(mas_column))
        self.tableWidget_2.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)

        n = 0
        mas_cell = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
        for j in range(len(mas_column) - 1):
            for i in range(len(mas_row)):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily('Montserrat')
                font.setPointSize(6)
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                item.setFont(font)
                item.setText(mas_cell[n])
                n += 1
                self.tableWidget_2.setItem(i, j, item)

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window1 = MainWindow()
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

мой `stylesheet` :

```
QTableWidget {
    selection-background-color: #ffffff;
    selection-color: #000000;
    gridline-color: #000000;
}
QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
QTableWidget QTableCornerButton::section {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
QHeaderView::section:horizontal
{
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
QHeaderView::section:vertical
{
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}
QTableWidget {
    border: 0px solid ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как создать таблицу только для чтения без возможности выделения,
> редактирования содержимого таблицы и его размера?

Пример кода для одной таблицы (вторая, мне кажется, не нужна)

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QAbstractItemView

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    table = QTableWidget()
    table.setColumnCount(6)
    table.setRowCount(10)

    # Запретить выбор элементов
    table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)

    # Запретить фокус (убираем рамку выделения ячейки)
    table.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

    # И никакого редактирования
    table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

    # установка стилей
    table.setStyleSheet(...)

    # заполнение таблицы
    q = 0
    for i in range(table.columnCount()):
        for j in range(table.rowCount()):
            table.setItem(j, i, QTableWidgetItem(f'{q + 1}'))
            q = q + 1

    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Я бы ещё сюда пожалуй добавил ```table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)```, так как ```table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)``` запрещает редактирование только по горизонтале а надо ещё и по вертикале

Comment: @assert это лишь пример, отвечающий на вопрос - остальное это ваше видение как оно должно быть

Answer (score 2):

А если проще?

```
table.setEnabled(False)
table.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;color: black;")
```

Comment: Я пробовал ранее данный способ но в таком случае scrool bar не прокручивается.